# Scrapy MySQL pipeline: spider closed before pipeline finished

Tags: mysql, scrapy

I use scrapy to crawl a page which contains a list of items, and I save each of the item in MySQL databases. 
But the problem is that I found spider closed before all items are stored in mysql. Each time I ran the spider the result count is different.
Could you please help let me know how to solve this?

Below is my sample code:

Spider

```
class FutianSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'futian_soufang'
allowed_domain = ["fang.com"]
start_urls = []

def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.count = 0
    pass

def closed(self, reason):
    print "*" * 20 + str(self.count)

def start_requests(self):
    url = "http://fangjia.fang.com/pghouse-c0sz/a085-h321-i3{}/"
    response = requests.get(url.format(1))
    response.encoding = 'gb2312'
    strpages = Selector(text=response.text).xpath('//p[contains(@class, "pages")]/span[last()]/a/text()').extract()

    # print response.text

    pages = int(strpages[0])
    for num in range(1, pages + 1):
        yield scrapy.Request(url.format(num), callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    houses = response.xpath("//div[@class='list']//div[@class='house']")

    for house in houses:
        # house = Selector(house.decode("UTF-8", 'ignore'))
        self.count += 1
        housespan_hyperlink = house.xpath(".//span[@class='housetitle']/a")
        house_title = housespan_hyperlink.xpath("text()").extract()[0].strip()
        house_link_rel = housespan_hyperlink.xpath("@href").extract()[0].strip()
        house_link = response.urljoin(house_link_rel)
        # if isinstance(house_link_rel, list) and len(house_link_rel) > 0:
        #     house_link = response.urljoin(house_link_rel)

        address = house.xpath(".//span[@class='pl5']/text()").extract()[0].strip()

        esf_keyword = u'二手房'

        esf_span = house.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'%s')]" % (esf_keyword))
        esf_number = esf_span.xpath("./a/text()").extract()[0].strip()
        esf_number = int(re.findall(r"\d+", esf_number)[0])
        esf_link = esf_span.xpath("./a/@href").extract()[0].strip()

        zf_hyperlink = house.xpath(".//span[@class='p110']/a")
        zf_number = zf_hyperlink.xpath("text()").extract()[0].strip()
        zf_number = int(re.findall(r"\d+", zf_number)[0])
        zf_link = zf_hyperlink.xpath("@href").extract()[0].strip()

        price = 0
        try:
            price = int(house.xpath(".//span[@class='price']/text()").extract()[0].strip())
        except:
            None

        change = 0.0
        try:
            increase_span = house.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'nor')]")
            changetext = increase_span.xpath("text()").extract()[0].strip()
            change = float(changetext[:changetext.index('%')])
            if len(increase_span.css(".green-down")) > 0:
                change *= -1
        except:
            None

        print house_title, house_link, address, esf_number, esf_link, zf_number, zf_link, price, change

        item = XiaoquItem(
            title=house_title,
            url=house_link,
            address=address,
            esf_number=esf_number,
            esf_link=esf_link,
            zf_number=zf_number,
            zf_link=zf_link,
            price=price,
            change=change
        )
        yield item
```

Item:

```
class XiaoquItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = Field()
    url = Field()
    address = Field()
    esf_number = Field()
    esf_link = Field()
    zf_number = Field()
    zf_link = Field()
    price = Field()
    change = Field()
```

Pipeline:

```
class MySQLPipeLine(object):
def __init__(self):
    settings = get_project_settings()
    dbargs = settings.get('DB_CONNECT')
    db_server = settings.get('DB_SERVER')
    dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(db_server, **dbargs)
    self.dbpool = dbpool

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.dbpool.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):

    if isinstance(item, XiaoquItem):
        self._process_plot(item)
    elif isinstance(item, PlotMonthlyPriceItem):
        self._process_plot_price(item)
    return item

def _process_plot(self, item):
    # run db query in thread pool
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self._handle_error, item)
    # query.addBoth(lambda _: item)



def _conditional_insert(self, conn, item):
    # create record if doesn't exist.
    # all this block run on it's own thread
    conn.execute("select * from houseplot where title = %s", item["title"])
    result = conn.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level = log.DEBUG)
    else:
        conn.execute("insert into houseplot(title, url, address, esf_number, esf_link, zf_number, zf_link, price, price_change, upsert_time) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", \
                     (item["title"], item["url"], item["address"], int(item["esf_number"]), item["esf_link"], item["zf_number"], item["zf_link"], item["price"], item["change"], datetime.datetime.now())
                     )
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

def _handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)


def _process_plot_price(self, item):
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert_price, item)
    query.addErrback(self._handle_error, item)

def _conditional_insert_price(self, conn, item):
    # create record if doesn't exist.
    # all this block run on it's own thread
    conn.execute("select * from houseplot_monthly_price where title = %s and price_date= %s", (item["title"], item["price_date"]))
    result = conn.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Price Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
        conn.execute(
            "insert into houseplot_monthly_price(title, price_date, price) values (%s, %s, %s)", (item["title"], item["price_date"], item["price"])
            )
        log.msg("Price Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
```

Comment: generally , workflow would be spider code parse and yields item object -> item object will be sent to pipline and after you process it , you will return it back to scrapy and if there is no more request , spider will then close the spdier....but it should not close the spider before item is procesed in piline

Comment: try using json feed exporter as well and see if no of items in json is matches with no of recors stored in mysql